# Violating the Shabbat across time zones

Tags: shabbat, eretz-yisrael, internet, zemanim, electricity

Let's say I'm on my computer in the United States on a Friday afternoon, well before the sun has set in the US, but after it has set in Israel. If I access an Israeli website during this time, am I violating the Shabbat? Or could I potentially be causing an Israeli Jew to violate the Shabbat?